# using reserved words in column names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Using reserved names as column names in pandas does not provide an error or warning message. The code just runs through without doing anything. Is there a way to turn on some kind of warning to prevent use of reserved words as column names?

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd

index_names = ['1','2','3']
col_names = ['median','A']

df = pd.DataFrame(index = index_names, columns = col_names)
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
df.ix[1].A = 12
df.ix[1].median = 12
print df
```

Output:

```
 median    A
1    0    0
2    0    12
3    0    0
```

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Well, there are *some* [reserved names](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), but generally you're right - it's perfectly legal to shoot yourself in the foot by reusing names of built-in objects, and this principle appears to extend to pandas...

Comment: This is why, in my usage of `pandas`, I resort to using the bracket notation of accessing the columns rather than the dot notation. While the latter is convenient, sometimes you'll not only end up shooting your foot, you'll even end up amputating the wrong leg.

Comment: Maybe reserved words is not the right terminology. I meant words that are reserved for special purpose. In pandas 'median' has a special meaning http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.median.html . However, I was not aware of that and named a data column as 'median'. One would expect that if there is a conflict, there would be an error or warning message. I just wanted to know how I can catch these errors in the future.

Comment: A very explicit method is to store all these terms into a list and check each column name versus said list. However, this might be a slightly tedious undertaking for each involved library (I don't think you'd stop at `pandas` alone). "Basic" Python is easy enough since you can invoke the `builtin` method anytime and just compare it there.

Comment: So `df.ix[1]` already had a member named 'median'? There's no flag afaik to warn every time a name is re-bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, unlike other languages there really isn't a concept of variables. Python has names that point to objects.

Since Python is not strict typed (unlike Java or C++ for example), you have the flexibility to assign names to other objects, even names that point to functions (since functions are, like everything else, an object).

Although this is extremely flexible (it allows to easily overwrite functionality of objects by overwriting the names of functions), it does mean that Python will not warn you if you try to do something that impacts a [built-in name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html). This is called *shadowing*.

It is just one of the tradeoffs of having a flexible type system, and something Python programmers need to be aware of.

Here is a canonical example:

```
>>> type(id)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> id(4)
10677280
>>> id = 5
>>> type(id)
<type 'int'>
>>> id(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, according to your example once I have renamed a column 'median' that should just overwrite the builtin median method/function and I should still get the output I wish right?

Comment: It will depend on how Pandas maps your column names. In your example, you have just overwritten the median property (if it existed) to 12.

Comment: Also something to keep in mind is the [behavior](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/90dc9aeebfad683b1f9792a228412861e9330f47/pandas/core/frame.py#L1058) when using `df.itertuples()` to iterate over the `df`.  Reserved words like `return` in a column header will be replaced by positional names like `_4`